# How long will it take for the secondary (accompanying person) to get the Express Entry PR Canada?

Tags: canada, express-entry

My husband and I got our ITA for Express Entry Canada and we were unmarried when we applied for this. And we got married a month before we got the ITA. Now, should we decline my ITA and accept & continue my Husband's application? I being the accompanying person on his application, how long would it take for me to get the PR card? 
Would the processing still be the same if I were to apply separately?

Please help.

Thanks,
Atulya

Answer (score 1):

The target to process a FSW application is reportedly 6 month which after, the main and all dependants receive a passport request email (to stamp a visa).

In your case the main applicant should inform IRCC about the change of his/her marital status through [web form](https://www.cic.gc.ca/english/contacts/web-form.asp) ASAP and they will ask for additional applicable documents. This may inevitabely increase your time-line (standard 6 month).

The main applicant wouldn’t need to withdraw his/her ITA. If you are required to do so, they will instruct you in response of your web form.